# Need assistance with code where it claims code not declared in this scope (C++)

Tags: c++, scope, declaration

I am practicing using multiple files for C++ in Code::Blocks.  I have three files, two source files named main.cpp and Cat.cpp, and a header file named Cat.h.  Though I declare a function designed to output text in Cat.h, the implementation in the main function returns the error "'speak' was not declared in this scope."

I tried researching the error, but that was tricky because it's such a general error that can occur for a wide variety of reasons.  I tried carefully checking for syntax errors or improper #include statements in my code, but I can't find anything.

This is in my main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.cpp"
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

     speak();

     return 0;
}
```

this is my Cat.h file:

```
#ifndef CAT_H_INCLUDED
#define CAT_H_INCLUDED

void speak();

#endif
```

and this is my Cat.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

void speak(){
    cout << "Meow!!" << endl;
}
```

I am expecting speak() to run, but the error says it is not declared in this scope.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you sure you're compiling this exact code? Also, you're not supposed to include .cpp files (`#include "Cat.cpp"`). This shouldn't cause any problems here, but it's not going to work in more complex cases.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Actually, it should, as `speak` would be defined both in main.cpp and cat.cpp and this is the proof that the OP does not link both object files together.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I am wondering if the problem is the location of my files.  Can that cause a build to fail?

Comment: If the compiler couldn't find an `#include`d file, it would tell you that.

Comment: What command are you using to compile your program? Expanding on what @Quimby said, I suspect you are compiling only main.cpp, which is why you decided to #include Cat.cpp. Instead, you should pass both .cpp files to your compiler (an executable can come from multiple .cpp files, there's no need to have a 1-to-1 relationship between .cpp files and generated binaries!), and you should only include .h files. If you could [edit] your question adding the precise command you use, it would help!

Comment: It is preferable to copy-and-paste the error message into the question, rather than give your interpretation of the message. (After all, if you knew exactly what the error was trying to tell you, you wouldn't need to ask us what's wrong.)

Comment: Okay I am a bit confused because my code wasn't working yesterday, but it's working today, and I made no changes.  Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Edit:  Just to make sure it doesn't happen again, let me respond to the assistance.  The exact error was "'speak' is not declared in this scope."  @fabioTurati : I am pretty new.  How do I differentiate building just one file or building all of them?

Comment: Are you building the program using Code Block's "Build" function? I don't know Code Blocks, but can you verify what command that translates to? Otherwise, I suppose the compiler you are using is gcc: can you open a shell, go to the directory where you have your code, and type `gcc -o single_source main.cpp`? Does it generate an executable called "single_source"? In general, it shouldn't. The command you should be using is `gcc -o multiple_sources main.cpp Cat.cpp`.

Comment: @FabioTurati I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking me to do.  My understanding of file systems is a bit limited.

Comment: I suppose you are building your program clicking on a button in Code Block's interface. To identify the issue that you had, and that seems to have disappeared now, it would be better to build it the old way, that is by typing commands from a command prompt. I've given you the commands to use for it. If you've never used a shell before, this could take some time, and maybe it isn't worth it, as you have other things to focus on. Still, I recommend you to read a tutorial on how to use a shell, and how to compile a program from it. It might be very useful in the future!